# Extract files in order by numbers at end of filename (windows)

Tags: windows, command-line, sorting, filenames, extract

I want to use a Windows .bat file to extract a number of files in a folder.

I have files with numbers at the end of filename, just before the extension, and I need to extract them in order of these numbers which are in sequence.

The files are all named : xxxxxxx_1234.zip, and I mainly want to sort by the last two numbers.

The order matters, because files in the sucessive numbers contain newer versions that the previous numers.
So, if I have a number of files (a simplified example): xxxxxxx_1234.zip xxxxxxx_1235.zip xxxxxxx_1236.zip.

So some files in 1236 will be newer than 1235, and some files in 1235 will be newer than 1234. So I need to order mainly by the last two digits.
This is enforced on me, I **cannot** change that..

I have the extraction part, but it extracts all files alphabetically, but that is not the correct order for what I want to do.

Can you guys help me with this please ?

My existing code:

```
rmdir /s /q done unzip
mkdir done
mkdir unzip
cd unzip

    FOR /D /r %%F in ("*") DO (
        pushd %CD%
        cd %%F
            FOR %%X in (*.zip) DO (
                "C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe" x ..\"%%X"
            )
        popd
    )
```

Kind regards,

Anthony

Comment: "named : `xxxxxxx_1223.zip`, and I mainly want to sort by the last two numbers" – `1223` is one number. Do you mean "the last two digits"?

Comment: Why does the unzip order matter? It's just going to drop them all in the same place sorted by default. If you need to concatenate segments, you'd do better to concentrate on renaming into a better file name convention first, that the zip utility will auto-recognise - .z01, .z02 etc

Comment: Hi, it should be xxxxxxx_1234.zip.

Comment: Original post updated